# Flutter Firebase Database Class in multiple files

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a big project and manage a lot of data with firebase. For this I have a class "MyFirestoreDatabase" in which I have every single firebase function, which I then call from my providers.

The problem is, that the **MyFirestoreDatabase class has gotten really really big** and I would want to split it up into **sub classes and different files**.

Every time I call a firebase function I use MyFirestoreDatabase.instance.functionName(),
so I don't think I want different classes, because then I would have multiple instances of the database open at the same time right?

Would it work to extend the class?

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase` is the accessor class for the Firebase Realtime Database, not for Cloud Firestore. So if that is the class you're using, can you update your tags to reflect this?

Comment: I'm sorry it's actually called FireStoreDatabase in my file but that is an arbitrary name, I will update my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `FirebaseFirestore.instance` always returns the same (default) instance, no matter how many times you call it. This is the essence of the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

So calling it in each separate class won't make any change in resource consumption, nor in the number of connections to the backend servers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess what confused me was, that I never call FirebaseFirestore.instance, at initialization I call it once with

static DocumentReference userReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('stringOfUserDoc');

and from then on only use the userReference.
What would be the correct architecture to make all Firebase.instance calls correpond to just this user document and subcollections of it? 
And in which file would I have to use FireStoreDatabase._init_()?
I can't find any examples online of anything more complex than trivial examples.

Comment: You need to initialize the Firebase SDKs before you first use any of its services, so I typically do that in my `main` function before even initializing the UI.